# How to avoid circular reference in Qlikview

Tags: circular-reference, qlikview

Specific to this data structure:

[image: Data Structure]

I cannot link `LOL_Connection` to `LOL_User` — renaming `Connection.USERID AS %USERID` — otherwise I get a circular reference exception.

What possible workarounds?

**I wish I can get both connections and bids along with user data**

Please note `LOL_User` is linked to other tables not displayed here for sake of brevity.

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396393/qlikview-circular-reference?rq=1 ?

Comment: I saw, but just can't get the point with my data structure...

Comment: I don't know your applikation logic, but may be you can load the LOL_User twice (LOL_User_1 and LOL_User_2 [or LOL_User_Con and LOL_User_Bid]). And then change the USERID to USERID_1 and USERID_2.